# How to prevent noise when connecting "speaker out" of SIM800L to audio mixer?

Tags: amplifier, audio, noise, gsm, passive-filter

**Aim**

I'm trying to build a device to be used for call center agents. They could make calls via this device, which could be connected to a PC to be able to record this conversation.

**Solution**

Build this device with GSM, Arduino and audio mixer, to mix both the voice of the client and the agent, then send it by audio jack to a PC.

**Question**

I'd like to ask how I could remove noise produced when I connect the SIM800L to the audio mixer? When I connect the audio mixer input to SPKP with common ground for both circuit and Arduino, I get a lot of noise. But when I connect my headphone to SPKP & SPKN, I get pure sound with no noise.

I tried to use a passive low-pass filter to prevent any noise due to GSM freq (850 MHz, 1900 MHz) and allow audio voice frequency.

Any suggestion please?

**Notice**

I can't connect SPKP to the input of the audio mixer and connect SPKN to the audio mixer ground, since it produces GSM error. So I have to connect only SPKP to the input of the audio mixer.

[image: wiring diagram]

---

I found this circuit configuration on the datasheet of the SIM800L. If I applied it to my GSM and connected it to the audio mixer, will it solve the issue?

[image: Speaker interface circuit from SIM800L datasheet]

Comment: headphone, amplifier, sim800l? Without a schematic of how these things are connected, where your antenna is, what you're trying to build, this will be impossible to answer!

Comment: ok .. i will upload schematic ... right now , with more details